# How to rename a column in AWS Athena output csv?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I want to replace a column name in output of Athena query. I can not change the name in the database. Is it possible to rename it directly?

```
case when kpi in ('Brand Searches') then replace('Total Searches','Brand Searches') end
```

Here is the output:

```
KPI                  _col7                
Brand Searches       Total Searches
```

A new column was created, I want only to rename the column. Is there an easy way out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alias the column to the name of your choice:

`select count(*) as "number of counts" from ...`